# Ambiguous column name error SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am receiving the error 'Ambiguous column name 'ClaimID' for the following:

```
USE ERSBI_Claims_Warehouse
GO

SELECT 
    ClaimID             AS vClaimID,
    DevelopmentTimeID   AS vDevelopmentTimeID,
    UnderwritingYear    AS vUnderwritingYear,
    IncurredClaimCount  AS vIncurredClaimCount,
    PaidClaimCount      AS vPaidClaimCount,
    EstimateClaimCount  AS vEstimateClaimCount

FROM
    FactClaimSnapshotbreakdownClaimCount as fcbscc

INNER JOIN ERSBI_Warehouse.dbo.FactClaimAccidentYear AS fcay
    ON fcbscc.ClaimID = fcay.ClaimID

WHERE
    fcbscc.BreakdownIntermediateLevel = 'TPP'
AND UnderwritingYear > 2013
```

I am very new to SQL however I think I have included all of the relevant table names. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should get in the habit of ALWAYS including the alias in front of the column name in your queries. It not only eliminates this issue is makes it easier for you to maintain your queries because you can easily see which table a column belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting just `ClaimId` in your `SELECT` statement, but you have multiple tables with `ClaimId` in it.

You need to tell it which table you're pulling from.

Based on your join:

```
fcbscc.ClaimID = fcay.ClaimID
```

Doing either

```
SELECT fcbscc.ClaimID
```

or

```
SELECT fcay.ClaimID
```

will suffice

Answer (score 6):

Since `ClaimID` exists in both tables you need to name from which you want to select:

```
SELECT fcbscc.ClaimID ...
```